# Search results page - wrong number of products per page

Tags: catalogsearch, pagination, pager

In search results page, I'm not getting the correct number of products on each page. I have set the following in local.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalogsearch_result_index>
        <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>30</limit></action>
            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>30</limit></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>
</layout>
```

The limiter selectbox in pagination toolbar, indeed displays "Show 30" as selected value. But in product list, there are only 9 products displayed in each results page.

I can't find a solution to this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well done for doing local.xml, however, for the list part of category and search result pages layout updates in local.xml cannot be relied upon. I cannot fully remember the reason for this, but I think this is the problem here!!!

Try moving your layout updates to the .xml files in your theme (as copied from base, the proper Magento way).

If this does not work... Maybe the templates rather than the layout is where the problem is.

The search results use the same category list templates as the main category pages. The side nav, header and other page elements may be different but that main list template is the same.

Go into admin->system->config->catalog->catalog and change the products per page there, as predicted this should affect the products in your template.

Next, how to fix. If it wasn't the local.xml problem mentioned above, I suspect that the $collection is being created properly, paginating on 30, however, the template is hard wired to different settings, to show 9. If this changes based on the catalog admin settings you are nearer to knowing what is going on.

Comment: Hi & thank you for your suggestions. I have tried moving layout updates to many .xml files, such as catalogsearch, catalog etc. The effect is the same with local.xml file. The pagination toolbar has the correct products-per-page numbers, and the number of pages is also correct. The inner product list is still displaying 9 products though.

Comment: The admin->system->config->catalog->catalog settings are also correctly set

Comment: The products list is generated from template/catalogseach/results.phtml file, and the $this->getProductListHtml() function. I can't see any customization that could affect the product list here...

Comment: I found out, that the function responsible for this is in template/catalog/product/list.phtml. It's the $this->getLoadedProductCollection() function. This collection counts 9 products instead of 30, but I can't see how to fix this....

Comment: After countless hours of searching, I finally found out that this issue was caused by a custom theme module. Thank you for your help anyway.